# mongodb queryset save does not do update , only insert

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

In my flask app:

```u
class places(db.Document):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'places',
        'allow_inheritance': False,
    }
    name = db.StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    loc= db.GeoPointField(required=True)

x = places(loc=[-87,101], name="test")
places.save(x)
```

However, I want only to insert the document if it's new, otherwise I want to update the row.
I'm not sure how to use upsert/update.

I encounter an error which tells me to save before update (I'm using mongoengine in my flask app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this that way. 
But you can try next one:

First try to get object from db

```
place = places.objects(name="test").first()
if place:
    #update here
    place.loc = [88,102]
else:
    #create new here
    place = places(loc = [-87,101], name="test")
place.save()
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how i do #update here . is it like  places.update?

Comment: if i try to use places.objects(name = "test") nothing is returned in my flask app, while in mongodb the db.places.find({name : "test"}) returns results . Please help @Elephant

Comment: oh, that was my mistake. I fix that in my answer. places.objects(name="test").first() of course

Comment: thanks for your help @Elephant , but if i try to print the places.objects(name="test").first() on my console . it gives me [] , while i have a row in my database which is returned with db.places.find()

Comment: I figured out the problem.. Your solution is perfect. My flask app had to be restarted since it was using the old db context. Thank you  @Elephant